# Sails 500 error on the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js

[image: I hope you can help me, so far I]

I have a 500 error on the server, I'm using mongo and sails, investigate and until now I can not solve it, I'm waiting for your response thanks.

Use sails generate api, and when I use localhost: 1737 / book / create? Title = hello, And do not create it, I get the error: unknown rule: require, check many times the code there is no error, investigate and the error is In the mongo server, mongod runs without errors, but when I run mongo I get this error:
Failed:
Connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js: 237: 13
@ (Connect): 1: 6
Exception: connect failed
I hope you can help me, thank you

Comment: Please describe the problem you are experiencing in detail and what you have tried to solve it.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `Module.exports.models = {connection: 'mongodb', migrate: 'alter'};`     
 This is the model where migrations and connection are established `module.exports.connections = {localDiskDb: {adapter: 'sails-disk'}, mongodb: {adapter: 'sails-mongo', host: 'localhost', port: 27017, user: '', // optional password: '', // optional database: 'camaleon' // optional},};` And this is the connection, as I said okay that's why I do not consider putting the code or maybe it's s

Comment: If anyone knows if the latest version of mongo is compatible with version 0.12 of sails, maybe that is the problem, I read it in a comment, if so, how can I solve it

Comment: Show your `api/models/Book.js` code

Answer (score 0):

Try to use url for mongo

```
    mongoDBLocal: {
      adapter: 'sails-mongo',
      url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/your-db-name',
      schema: true
    }

//URL FORMAT
//url: 'mongodb://<YOUR DB USER USERNAME>:<YOUR DB USER PASSWORD>@<YOUR IP>:<YOUR PORT>/<YOUR DATABASE NAME>'
```